# Iteration in templates

Tags: django

I want to be able to do the equivalent of <% for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {} %>  in JSP to Django. I have come up with something like this but it returns a TemplateSyntaxError. can any one show me how to iterate over models properly?

```
 {% for s in Student.objects.all() %}
    <article class="span4">
      <div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <img src="{% static "img/student1.jpg" %}">
        </div>
        <h1>{{s.first_name} {s.last_name}}</h1>
        <p>{{s.story}}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{s.first_name} {s.last_name}}` is a syntax error, it should be `{{s.first_name}} {{s.last_name}}`

And you should pass `Student` to template rendering context.

Comment: Student.objects.all() also throws an error.do you know why? thanks!

Comment: @EmanuelSaringan `{% for s in Student.objects.all %}`, the braces in template will raise errors (or you can use template filters).

Comment: Maybe you should get a queryset first in views.py, like `students = Student.objects.all()`, then pass students to the template context.